# What mindset changes are helpful to get the most out of LOTRO?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I'm a 5 year WoW player picking up LOTRO for the first time.  What sort of mindset do I need to be in to get the most out of the game?

Here are a few common (not necessarily mine) WoW mindsets. What is the LOTRO take on each of these?

- Blitz to maximum level because endgame is where it's at.
- Once at maximum level it's all about gear, gear, gear.
- Instance groups must be 1 tank, 1 healer, 3 dps.
- Professions are relatively useless (in terms of pve/pvp performance) except for the perks at or near maximum skill.
- Get every achievement possible (is there a LOTRO equivalent to achievements?)
- etc... feel free to add your own and provide how LOTRO is different

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'll try and take these on one bullet at a time

- Blitz to maximum level because endgame is where it's at.

No. Take your time. Most of the content is in the leveling. Do the Epic quests for the story. Once you hit endgame, make another character and do different quests to get to the end, since you probably missed at least 60% of the content your first time through.

- Once at maximum level it's all about gear, gear, gear.

Yes, to a small extent. Most people get a bit bored at max level, because there isn't much in the way of horizontal development.

- Instance groups must be 1 tank, 1 healer, 3 dps.

Generally, yes, but LOTRO is fairly flexible. There are 6 slots for a normal instance groups, but many 3-man instances are here and more are coming. It's not unheard of to see 2 tanks and a DPS take on a few of these. Also, there are a few classes that break the mold of the Tank/Heal/DPS trifecta, so combinations can be more creative.

- Professions are relatively useless (in terms of pve/pvp performance) except for the perks at or near maximum skill.

Sadly, yes. Cook and Scholar are two notable exceptions, since they can make popular consumables. Other than that, quest gear is usually much better.

- Get every achievement possible (is there a LOTRO equivalent to achievements?)

In LOTRO, there are Deeds. Hundreds! (Thousands?) Some examples include: Getting the highest reputation possible with all elf factions, killing 240 lava worms, or finding the bottom of a well the "hard way." It would take you quite a while to complete all them, but it seems like completionists have fun with it.

- etc... feel free to add your own and provide how LOTRO is different

For the most part, PvP and Endgame are weak in LOTRO. This is more than made up for by the depth of the story in quests, especially the Epic Quest line. If you're a die-hard-endgamer, there are still raids and such available, but it's not quite the hardcore community that WoW is.

Comment: +1 for good answer.  But everytime I read something like this I find myself wondering why I'm the only person in the world who thinks WoW has a weak endgame as well...

Comment: @Shinrai I hear you. That's why I said those mindsets were not necessarily mine.  I'm tired of the get-gear-omg-new-content-get-more-gear-rinse-repeat cycle.

Comment: If you're tired of the endgame circle, then I'd definitely recommend LOTRO. About half the updated content is geared towards under-cap levels, sometimes replacing entire zones. It really is a whole new game when you bring a new class through a few months after your first capped player.

Answer (score 6):

For a great percentage of the time, crafted items beat quest reward items. Crafting is essential to the game, it's community and kinships.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to address your questions one-by-one:

- **Reach End Game Because That Is Where Everything Is**

The endgame in LOTRO has said to be weak. What you *do* want to do is get to level 20 (max level is 75, soon wil be 85) as fast as you can. Note that going up levels in LOTRO is slower than in WoW. At 20, you unlock The Great Barows, your first Full-Fellowship instance, and Skirmishes. Once you get there, you can get a nice armor set that will last you until you unlock the next instance: Garth Aragwen, or you get the Evendim armor set.

- **Groups must have 1 tank, 1 healer, 3 DPS**

Again, no. First, LOTRO has group sizes of 6. And, that isn't the ideal group makeup. I usually like to have 1 Tank, 2 Healers, 1 DPS (me), 2 special (burgular, who starts powerful group attacks/heals and either another DPS or Captain/Loremaster. Loremaster does CC, and Captain Buffs and Heals)

- **Crafting is useless**

Exact opposite. Once you are out of the beginning instance, you can get crafting. You can then immediately craft almost anything, from Armor to Weapons to Jewlerry to Food to Scrolls-That-Give-Nice-Effects and Class Items.

In LOTRO, as soon as you get a vocation, which is made of 3 professions, you get the standard lvl 7 recipes (unless you make Heavy Armor, in which case you get lvl 15 armor recipes, but the shield starts at 7). In order to craft these items, you must obtain certain components, like Ore and Wood. These must be gathered using one of the three professions you get in your vocation. You get these from around the landscape and looting enemies. However, you must first equip a certain tool, depending on what you are trying to get. For Ore, you need a mining-axe. For wood, you need a wood-axe. When you first get your profession, you get Inferior tools. You can buy Normal quality tools from the specific Crafting Vendor. If you have Metalsmith profession, you can use that to make better tools, which let you harvest ore faster, and get a higher Critical Success Chance. (Critted items have better dmg/stats). You can go onto Lotro-Wiki.com to get more information.

At near max level, Metalsmithing gets a little useless, as you get Class Armor Sets. But Legendary Items can be crafted.

- **Grab Every Achievement**

Yes! You should do this! But unfortunately it gets really boring to do this. LOTRO has Deeds, not Achievements. Deeds give you FREE Turbine Points (which are used to buy premium items) and Virtues, which give you a stat boost, except they are pretty useless. Also, you get a Title, which shows off that you killed 30 trolls, etc.

- **Other Comments**

If you have more questions, leave a comment or check LOTRO-Wiki.com. Or, ask the Forums or here. I frequently check the [lord-of-the-rings-online](/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings-online) tag.

Another thing I would say is that if you haven't picked a class, make a Elf-Hunter. In LOTRO each of the races get special stat boosts. Elves get +agility, which gives you +hit-chance, +crit_chance, +ranged-damage, but unfortunately Elves get -regeneration rates from a loss of Fate. Which doesn't really affect you. The Good outnumbers the bad.

Also Elves get a power-boost skill at a high level, which is useful when they are  in a group on a long fight, as Hunters really burn down the Power bar.

Answer (score 2):

As a 20yr Everquest vet, 10 Yr lotro and 3yr WoW, I'd would definitely suggest that following the storyline and doing every quest, no pun intended, will give you a depth of satisfaction not equivalent to the standard hack-and-slash at the end game. if you enjoy the original story, then you're in for a treat. If all you want is quick results and quick victory, there's other alternatives out there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still very new to LotRO, but concerning endgame, it is to be noted that LotRO is far from complete. The Rise of Isengard extension will only be released near the end of the year. Then there will at least be another major extension with the direct war against Sauron... Only then we will be able to talk about any sort of "weakness of endgame", and considering the story, I certainly would not suppose it will be "weak"... :) After this, though, I have no idea what will happen of LotRO... Maybe some epilogue extension for "cleaning up" the remains of the dark forces...? Anyway, there is still a lot to enjoy until then.

The advantage of LotRO, is that it's now F2P, so even if you stop paying for VIP access between the extensions, you will still be able to come and play regularly, without too many restrictions (and most of them can be removed by going through the store, with the 500 points per month you get when you pay for VIP access).

Comment: You don't "reach endgame" in LotRO. You help free Middle-Earth. No more fighting? Heck, that's our very goal. For peace at last.